# Testing routings in linux (iptables)

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I have static routes today in linux, I will pass them with metrics, does anyone have any idea to check the route at the other end and if it goes down, the metric will be changed or something? so you don't have to change manually.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic routing table updates are handled with routing protocols, like RIP or OSPF.

You should configure routing protocol in your network, which will automatically handle routing updates based on link availability.